# How to set the EndPoint / Region for the C# .NET SDK : EC2Client?

Tags: amazon-s3, region, endpoint

In the JAVA SDK it's possible to set the endpoint, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162281/amazon-aws-java-api-i-dont-see-my-amis).

But how to do this for .NET SDK ? And what are the names to use?

Because it seems that a default endpoint "US East (Northern Virginia) Region" is always used.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regions and Endpoints can be found [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ec2_region).

And example how to connect to EU:

```
AmazonEC2 ec2 = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonEC2Client("key", "secret",
    new AmazonEC2Config
    {
        ServiceURL = "http://ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
    }
);
```

Answer (score 33):

You can also use an endpoint definitions delivered with [Amazon SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/latest/DeveloperGuide/init-ec2-client.html):

```
var ec2Client = new AmazonEC2Client(RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);
```

Since I believe hard-coding such values as endpoint addresses is not a best practice I use more configurable version (i.e. endpoint configured from web.config/app.config):

```
var region = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("eu-west-1");
var ec2Client = new AmazonEC2Client(region);
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Also I came across this while I was looking for a list of possible SystemName Strings that could be passed to the GetBySystemName method... Though I did not find the answer here I did find it at https://github.com/xamarin/amazon/blob/master/AWSSDK/RegionEndpoint.cs for anyone else that comes across this question looking for valid SystemName values.

Comment: GetBySystemName very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You can also define the aws region in your configuration file using the region code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="AWSProfileName" value="default"/>
    <add key="AWSRegion" value="eu-west-1"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then you can simply instanciate your ec2Client without any region:

```
var ec2Client = new AmazonEC2Client();
Console.WriteLine(ec2Client.Config.RegionEndpoint.DisplayName);
```

Output:

```
EU West (Ireland)
```

Regions and endpoint are defined here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html