# How to set RegionEndPoint for AWS AmazonSQSClient in C# on the App Config file

Tags: c#, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I have declared a RegionEndpoint on my app config like this

```
<add key="AWSRegion" value="EUWest1" xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
```

And on my program i'm tryna call this AWSRegion

```
 private static string RegionEndPoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSRegion"];
```

So when i declare my SQSClient i get an error that, Cannot convert from string to RegionEndPoint

```
var SQSClient = new AmazonSQSClient(credentials, RegionEndPoint);
```

i have tried making sense of this question here [How to set the EndPoint / Region for the C# .NET SDK : EC2Client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949671/how-to-set-the-endpoint-region-for-the-c-sharp-net-sdk-ec2client)

but its for EC2Client so it doesn't seem to work out for me.

i have also tried to declare the regionendpoint using the AWS SDK like this

```
private static RegionEndpoint RegionEndPoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSRegion"];
```

i also get an error which says cannot implicitly convert from type string to Amazon.RegionEndpoint

So if theres a way to add a RegionEndPoint in a config file and use it in an SQSClient please help me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSRegion"]` returns string value `EUWest1` but `RegionEndpoint` is a class.

`AmazonSQSClient` constructo expects an instance of class `RegionEndpoint` as second parameter but since you are passing string value, you are getting the error.

You can get the `RegionEndpoint` class instance from Configuration value using following approach.

`RegionEndpoint` class has a static method `GetBySystemName`. You need to pass the region name to this method and it would return appropriate instance of `RegionEndpoint` class.

But for this you need to have proper region name to be passed. You need to put that value in configuration. In your case, the configuration value should be `eu-west-1`. Configuration value `EUWest1` will not work here.

You can find all the valid region names of AWS [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html)

```
<add key="AWSRegion" value="eu-west-1" xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
```

With above configuration value you can use following code to get the Region based on it.

```
private static RegionEndpoint RegionEndPoint = 
      RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSRegion"]);
```

Above code will give you RegionEndPoint instance for `EU (Ireland) Region` region and now you can use it for `AmazonSQSClient` as following.

```
var SQSClient = new AmazonSQSClient(credentials, RegionEndPoint);
```

This will help you resolve the issue you are facing.